# Laravel Passport authentication : how to use code and state?

Tags: oauth-2.0, nuxt.js, laravel-passport, laravel-7

I'm authenticating to Laravel (7.3) Passport with the following configuration:

`nuxt.config.js`

```
  auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/login',
      home: '/'
    },
    strategies: {
      'laravel.passport': {
        url: 'http://laravel.test',
        client_id: '2',
        client_secret: 'S0gpcgfIDgbvIHCL3jIhSICAiTsTUMOR0k5mdaCi',
        redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:3000'
      }
    }
  }
```

Authentication method in `pages/login.vue`:

```
async nuxtLaravelPassport() {
  try {
    const response = await this.$auth
      .loginWith('laravel.passport')
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result)
      })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
},
```

It brings me to the authentication page of Laravel, then I log in and I'm redirected to my Nuxt.js home page with a `code` and `state` as parameters.

What should I do with these `code` and `state` ? Get a `token` ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Verify the state is the same you started the request and if it matches, post the code with the other parameters required by the token endpoint to issue the access token [reference](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/oidc/#token).